# Fetch data from nested nodes from Firebase real-time database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a quotes app in flutter using the real-time firebase backend.
So I want to fetch child node values. Here is my flutter code for fetching data and firebase database snapshot.

[image]

Flutter code for fetching data.

```
 Future<void> readData() async {
    List<String> MainList = [];
    List<String> SubListQuotes = [];
    databaseReference
        .child("Quotes_table")
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.value.forEach((key, values) {
        MainList.add(key);
        databaseReference
            .child("Quotes_table")
            .child(key)
            .once()
            .then((DataSnapshot snapshot2) {
          print(snapshot2.value);
        });

        // print(MainList);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could you explain where you are having problems, what you're trying to achieve and what you've already tried?

Comment: I have gotten only a category list only but I have failed to get all quotes against the category. Like against ability I want to all children quotes. -@dumazy

Comment: okay, and what is the issue you're having right now? Are you getting any data, if so what data, or is it throwing an error, if so what's the error? I recommend updating the question with this extra information

Comment: Yes, I am getting data but only categories data. I want to get all quotes against the category but I am failed to get data I don't know how I can get quotes against the category.